# Only if in "/" : alias ls='ls -I test'?

Tags: bash, ls, alias

I have the following in my `~/.bashrc` to hide the listing of `test` from the output of `ls`:

```
alias ls='ls -I test'
```

But I want it to only hide `test` if my current working directory is the root (`/`) folder, not if I am in some other folder.

How may I achieve this?

Comment: If the working directory is the root, or if the directory to be listed is the root?  Whilst the former is what you asked, I'm not sure that's what you really want!

Comment: Looks like someone is working on a user-level rootkit? :P

Comment: This is a bad idea. Better make a different alias and use that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this i thought it would work:

```
alias ls='[[ "$PWD" = "/" ]] && ls -I test ||ls'
```

`$PWD` is the current working directory
`&&` has the action to perform if pwd is `/` (condition check =true)
`||` has the action to perform if pwd is not `/`  (condition check=false)

But after carefull testing above solution IS NOT WORKING correctly.

On the other hand this will work ok as alternative to functions:

```
alias ls='{ [[ "$PWD" == "/" ]] && a="-I tmp2" ||a=""; };ls $a '
```

Or even better, similar to other answers but without the need of function:

```
alias lstest='{ [[ "$PWD" == "/" ]] && set -- "-I" "tmp2" || set --; }; ls "$@"'
```

Possible extra flags and/or full paths given in command line when invoking this alias are preserved and sent to ls.

Comment: A problem with this is that using `ls` from `/` will _always_ result in a listing of the current directory (`/`), no matter what the command line says.

Comment: @Kusalananda You are right , my solution was not correct. I would like you to have a look  in my alternative. I tested it and seems to work fine in Debian Bash. Definetely my answer should not have been marked as accepted before , but with the troll presence things got mixed up. I don't know if there is a way to transfer the "solution" mark to your answer as it was in the very beginning (before troll attacks)

Comment: @Kusalananda I just noticed that my alternative solution is similar to muru using a variable instead of `set` and not using a function but a direct alias.

Comment: The modified answer works, but has the side effect of setting `a` in the environment of the shell executing it. AFAIK, there's no immediate way around this with an alias like this.

Comment: Ah! `alias 'ls={ [[ "$PWD" == "/" ]] && set -- "-I" "tmp2"; }; ls "$@" '`, but that modifies the positional parameters instead...

Comment: @Kusalananda Does not work as expected, but this one does the trick : `alias 'lstest={ [[ "$PWD" == "/" ]] && set -- "-I" "tmp2" || set --; }; ls "$@"'`

Comment: `alias`es are nasty because they are some forms of macro expansion. Those particular alias can't stand for a real `ls` command. For instance, `! ls` or `foo || ls` won't do what you think. This really calls for a function. Note that the first example would run `ls` twice if the first one exits with a non-zero exit status.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In which first example among the three you refer to?

Comment: "without the need of function" isn't really a plus. Both of the "corrected" functions unnecessarily overwrite global variables that might be in use.

Answer (score 34):

```
ls () {
  case "$PWD" in
    /) command ls -I test "$@" ;;
    *) command ls "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```

The above shell function will test the current directory against `/` and executes the GNU `ls` command differently according to the outcome of the test.

`"$@"` will be replaced by the command line options and operands on the original command line.

We need to use `command ls` rather than just `ls` in the function to bypass the shell function lookup for `ls` (which would otherwise give us a nice infinite recursion).

Note that this will *not* use the ignore pattern if doing `ls /` from somewhere else, and that it *will* use the ignore pattern if doing, e.g., `ls /home/dvoo` from `/`.

To make it easier to remember what this actually does (six months down the line when you wonder what it's doing), use the long options:

```
ls () {
  case "$PWD" in
    /) command ls --ignore='test' "$@" ;;
    *) command ls "$@" ;;
  esac
}
```

---

Alternative implementation of the above function that will only call `ls` from one place (and which is shorter):

```
ls () {
  [ "$PWD" = "/" ] && set -- --ignore='test' "$@"
  command ls "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Use a function that tests if you're in `/` for `ls`:

```bsh
ls () {
    if [[ "$PWD" == / ]]
    then
        command ls -I test "$@"
    else
        command ls "$@"
    fi
}
```

This way, any arguments you pass to `ls` will still be used.

Or:

```bsh
ls () {
    if [ "$PWD" == / ]
    then
        set -- -I test "$@"
    fi
    command ls "$@"
}
```

Comment: That was a nice way of sorting out only having one call to `ls` in the function!